# Importing Flat file gives problems because user used "Wrap Text" in Excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio, csv, ssis

I am working in Visual Studio 2017 and doing a SSIS package.

I am importing a flat file (csv) which is seperated by ";". The file is exported from excel. 
When I import this file in Visual Studio I got problems because some cells is empty and have been "push". I tracked it down in the .csv file to find it is because it is like (example is x 2):

```
a 1;b 1;c 1;d 1;e 1;f 1;g 1
a 2;b 2;c 
2;d 2;e 
2;f 2;g 2
a 3;b 3;c 3;d 3;e 3;f 3;g 3
a 4;b 4;c 4;d 4;e 4;f 4;g 4
```

Opening the .csv file in excel (in which it has been written) I found that the problem arises when the user has used "Wrap Text" command in excel. Hence all the cells where the user has used "Wrap Text", gives the above problem in the .csv file.

Hence summing up I got and excel from a user, who is using "Wrap Text" in some cells. This gives a strange .csv file when exporting, and gives blank cells in Visual Studio when importing a flat file to a SSIS package.

I have tried to manually change this in the .csv file all the places where the error occurs, and after this the implementing works perfectly. However this is not a solution since I am receiving the .csv file from user, and I am not able to tell him to change this. 
Manually I corrected it to:

```
a 1;b 1;c 1;d 1;e 1;f 1;g 1
a 2;b 2;c 2;d 2;e 2;f 2;g 2
a 3;b 3;c 3;d 3;e 3;f 3;g 3
a 4;b 4;c 4;d 4;e 4;f 4;g 4
```

Question: Is it possible in Visual Studio doing a SSIS package to import a flat file source where the data is "messy" like this?

Thanks,
ss